# need to add a col conditionally

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have one table which I want to join with another. I would create a commmand in Crystal reports to get this output and change the names in the formulas easily.

I need something like this: only I need the sum from the second tbl.

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    rapklib.shpfrt a
    left outer join ralib.shpfrtc b

where idord# a = idord# b
```

the first is created as

```
CREATE VIEW 
    Ralib.shpfrt 
AS 
    SELECT 
        T01.IDORD#, 
        T01.IDDOCD, 
        T01.IDPRT#, 
        T01.IDSFX#, 
        T01.IDSHP#, 
        T01.IDNTU$, 
        T01.IDENT# ,
        ( T01.IDNTU$ * T01.IDSHP# ) AS LINTOT , 
        T02.IARCC3, 
        T02.IAPRLC , 
        T01.IDORDT, 
        T01.IDHCD3 
 FROM 
    STDTA.OEINDLID  T01 
    INNER JOIN STDTA.ICPRTMIA T02 ON T01.IDPRT# = T02.IAPRT# 

WHERE t01.iddocd > 20131231
```

the second is the same as the first but only will contain rows when there is a value in `idprt# = 'FRTCRDM'` then the sum we get there means there was a credit given for shipping charge (freight).

So I want to join them for use in a crystal report that will give me all the rows of the first but bring in the FRTCRDM amounts as well. Currently I am joining them when order# are = and thus only getting orders which have a FRTCRDM.

Comment: this is sqlserver or oracle.. always give tag to understand more easily. Also give some sample input data and output you want in table format.

Comment: Can you have another alias of the second table with a different join.